# Does MVC page load faster when you pass a empty model to View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have noticed that when you pass a model to the page loads faster than when you just return a **(strongly typed)** view in action. Also when you refer to **Model** in your lambda expression directly it is even faster

**Case 1**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}
```

In the view

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.field)<br />
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.field)
```

**Case 2**

```
private model1 = new model();
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(model1);
}

@Html.EditorFor(m => Model.field)<br />
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.field)
```

Maybe this is just special case on my computer but if it isn't Can some one please explain how these two different ways work? And also if this is good practise or not?

Comment: Did you test this while the debugger was attached or without the debugger while compiled with release? Did you tested this once of did you measure a few hundred calls? How did you measure it? Using `DateTime` subtractions or using the `Stopwatch` class?

Comment: i am currently trying to test this throughly. I have a huge model and I will post the results. The debugger was attached.

Comment: I have tested using stopwatch and indeed on my computer atleast it is true. I dont have a hosting plan so cannot check on network :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mvc page does load faster when you pass an empty Model. Here are the sample results. The test setting were VS 2012 express edition

```
@{ var c = DateTime.Now; System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(c); }// page start code
@{ var d = DateTime.Now; System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(d); System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(d - c); }// page end code

15/07/2013 11:31:06 ----- With empty model page start
15/07/2013 11:31:07 ----- With empty model page load completed
00:00:00.2680153    ----- With empty model total load time
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
15/07/2013 11:31:52 ----- Without empty model page start
15/07/2013 11:31:54 ----- With empty model page load completed
00:00:02.0501173    ----- With empty model total load time
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
15/07/2013 11:32:03 ----- Without empty model page start
15/07/2013 11:32:05 ----- With empty model page load completed
00:00:01.9641124    ----- With empty model total load time
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to profile your app or at the very least measure the performance using a Stopwatch. What is true for one user might not be true for others.

You need to test both methods under the same conditions (ideally production conditions) through many iterations to get a good idea if there is a significant difference.

Comment: Can you test this on a server if you have one plz.